# How to avoid ARR send request to closed web application on web farm

Tags: iis, iis-7, routes, iis-7.5, arr

I would like to know, if there a way with Microsoft ARR to test each web application on web farm.

The goal is avoid ARR to route the request if the web application is down.I mean, I know i can test the server with the healt test, but if an application is down du to a rapid fail protection, or any other reason the ARR route the request even if the application is failed. So i get intermittend interuption on some web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing built into ARR to do site level checking. You would need a PowerShell script for example to monitor for stopped appPools/sites and either try to automatically restart the appPool or reset the server affinity for that hostname so that the next request goes to a different server in the farm (not guaranteed depending on your load balance algorithm)